# Two errors in writing R code of QR decomposition using Gram-Schmidtand method and want to know why it went wrong

Tags: r

I write code manually of QR decomposition using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization:

```
A<-cbind(c(2,-2,18),c(2,1,0),c(1,2,0),c(2,3,4))
gsm<-function(X){
m<-ncol(X)
n<-nrow(X)
# initialize Q and R
q<-matrix(0,m,n)
r<-matrix(0,n,n)
v<-matrix(0,m,n)
# initialize V
v[,1]<-X[,1]
q[,1]<-v[,1]/sqrt(sum(v[,1]^2))  
r[1,1]<-t(X[,1])%*%q[,1]
for (i in 2:n){
dv<-0
for (j in 1:(i-1)) {
r[j,i]<-t(X[,i])%*%q[,j]
dv<-dv+r[j,i]*q[,j]
}
v[,i]<-X[,i]-dv
q[,i]<-v[,i]/sqrt(t(v[,i])%*%v[,i])  
r[i,i]<-t(X[,i])%*%q[,i]
}
qrreport<-list("Q"=q,"R"=r)
return(qrreport)
}
gsm(A)
```

However, the code doesn't work and gives me the error:
    Error in v[, 1] <- X[, 1] : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

And when I replace A with a 3*3 matrix: A<-cbind(c(2,-2,18),c(2,1,0),c(1,2,0)) and operate the function again, R throws a new error to me as:

```
Recycling array of length 1 in vector-array arithmetic is deprecated.
  Use c() or as.vector() instead.
Recycling array of length 1 in vector-array arithmetic is deprecated.
  Use c() or as.vector() instead.
$ Q
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.1097643  0.89011215 -0.4423259
[2,] -0.1097643  0.45314800  0.8846517
[3,]  0.9878783 -0.04855157  0.1474420

$R
         [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 18.22087 0.1097643 -0.1097643
[2,]  0.00000 2.2333723  1.7964082
[3,]  0.00000 0.0000000  1.3269776
```

I am very confused where I make mistakes and hope someone could help me debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `A` matrix has 3 rows and 4 columns, so in `gsm()` `m` is 4 and `n` is 3.  That means `v` has 4 rows and 3 columns, whereas `X`, which is really `A`, only has 3 rows.  When `v[, 1] <- X[, 1]` tries to put the 1st column of `X` into the first 
column of `A`, you get the error message you saw.

To debug things like this in RStudio, set a breakpoint on the line `v[, 1] <- X[, 1]` that caused the error, and look at the different items in the expression before executing it.  If you're not using RStudio, you can still set a breakpoint there using the `setBreakpoint` function, but it's a lot more work.